# Checking if Parameter is Null

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I'm trying to create a method that determines if my `id parameter` is null. If that `parameter` is null, then it should return true. If the `id parameter` has a value, then it should return false.

This seems fairly straight forward, but I can't seem to get it to work.

> **Resharper** has 2 remarks:
>
> 1. Expression is always false
> 2. Redundant conditional ternary expression usage.

**My Method:**

```
public bool IsPersonIdNull(int id)
{
    return id == null ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `int` is a struct. Structs cannot be null.

Comment: int or bool cannot be null (not the case for objects like string). If you want id to be nullable, declare "int ? id".

Comment: The second comment is because the expression itself returns a bool so you don't need the ternary to choose true or false, regardless of the `int` or `int?` confusion.

Comment: Please try to search for error messages as part of your investigation before asking the question. Microsoft provides search engine for that in addition to C#/VS: https://www.bing.com/search?q=Expression+is+always+false and https://www.bing.com/search?q=Redundant+conditional+ternary+expression+usage .

Answer (score 1):

That's because only *reference types* can by `null`. `int` is a *value type*. So by default it is `0`

Answer (score 1):

An `int` can never be null (it could be 0 though). This makes more sense:

```
public bool IsPersonIdNull(int? id)
{
    return id == null;
}
```

You don't need a ternary operator here, because the result of `id == null` is already a boolean.

Comment: thanks for your response, but this solution is not working correctly. I want the `IsPersonIdNull` method to handle all the logic this way I can call it on my validator. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Well, if your `id` is really an `int`, it can never be null, so the validator is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

How can it ever be null? `int` is a value type.  You would have to use a nullable int as the parameter as shown below:

```
 public bool IsPersonIdNull(int? id) 
 {
 }
```

You could then check if it has a value via the [HasValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
if (id.HasValue) {

}
```

Or simply use an inline return:

```
return id == null;
```

Comment: what logic would you put inside of the `if` statement?

Comment: @CodeChaser - `return false;` or you could use `return id == null;` like I have shown in my answer.

Comment: this solution is not working correctly. I want the `IsPersonIdNull` method to handle all the logic this way I can call it on my validator. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @CodeChaser - you haven't put all of the logic in your question....

Answer (score 0):

You can also create generic method for any type :

```
public bool IsPersonIdNull<T>(T instance)
{
    return instance == default(T);
}
```